# Can google search engine read meta tags that are echo using php

Tags: php, html, google-search, meta

I'm creating a website which is based on php; So i have a page

```
http://www.example.com/flie.php
```

Which changes it content depending on variable i put in url

```
http://www.example.com/flie.php?var=value
```

And insde of my .php file I want to have

```
<meta name="keywords" content="<?php echo $_GET["var"] ?>" />
```

Can google search engine read this

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about SEO.

Comment: `<?php ... ?>` statements are executed by the server. The client never receives them, only the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, There is no difference for google crawler wheather you write a static content in you HTML OR you write it dynamically using PHP or any other server side programming language.

Comment: Concur; note that Google (et al) frowns upon people changing the keywords (or the site in general) to give different information to their crawler versus what users see.

Comment: Thanks bro, saved my life